# How to display a Servant type signature as URL?

Tags: api, haskell, url, servant

I'm using [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/) with Servant and I would like to display API URLs as strings. I have the following value of type `BaseUrl`:

```
twitterBaseUrl :: BaseUrl
twitterBaseUrl = BaseUrl
    { baseUrlScheme = Https
    , baseUrlHost   = "api.twitter.com"
    , baseUrlPort   = 443
    , baseUrlPath   = "/2"
    }
```

And the following API type definition

```
type GetTweets
    =  RequiredHeader "Authorization" Text
    :> "users"
    :> Capture "id" Text
    :> "tweets"
    :> QueryParam "max_results" Int
    :> QueryParam "exclude" Text
    :> QueryParam "tweet.fields" Text
    :> QueryParam "end_time" Text
    :> Get '[JSON] (Page [Tweet])
```

What would be the easiest way to convert these values to the following URL?

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/2164623379/tweets?max_results=5&exclude=retweets&tweet.fields=created_at,public_metrics&end_time=2022-09-01T13%3A52%3A14Z
```